# joining in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

When i declare

```
 int[] a = { 1, 2 ,10,30};

 int[] b = { 10, 20, 30 };

  var q = from item1 in a
                     join item2 in b
                     on item1 equals item2
                     into g
                     select g
```

1)What is actually getting selected into g ? It is difficult to understand the `into` keyword. if you give example to explain the keyword `"into"`,i will be pleased.

2)

```
 How do the following code actually projected ?

1    from a in db.coll1
2    join b in db.coll2 on a.PK equals b.PK into b_join
3    from b in b_join.DefaultIfEmpty()
4    where
5      b.PK == null 
6   select new {
7      a.PK,
8      a.Value,
9      Column1 = (System.Int32?)b.PK,
10      Column2 = b.Value
    }
```

in line 2 we are using "b' to select the item
in line 3 also we are using the same b ,does it mean we are overriding the data we selected
at line 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You are doing a [*group join*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397905.aspx).  `g` will be an `IGrouping` for each element in `a`.  `g.Key` will be the element from `a`, and `g` (which implements `IEnumerable`) will contain all of the matching elements from `b`.  To understand this fully, try it out in [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net).  Also, read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397905.aspx).

2) The `into` keyword merges the first `b` into `b_join`, which will be an `IGrouping` as I described above.  After that, the first `b` is no longer in scope.

Answer (score 0):

If you use .NET Reflector on your compiled code, you can see that your first query is equivalent to the following:

```
IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>> q = a.GroupJoin(b,
   item1 => item1,
   item2 => item2,
   (item1, group) => group);
```

Note that you are performing a group join, but only returning the groups. Compare this with an ordinary join:

```
IEnumerable<int> q = a.Join(b,
    item1 => item1,
    item2 => item2,
    (item1, item2) => item2);
```

This returns the elements in b that matches to each a, if any such element exists.